# How caching works with Redis in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

I implement the following caching mechanism using Redis, but I am not sure how it works for different resultset.

***CacheConfig:***

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .serializeValuesWith(SerializationPair.fromSerializer(
                     new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer() {
        return (builder) -> builder
                .withCacheConfiguration("productCache",
                        RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                            .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(10)));
    }
}
```

***ProductService:***

```
@Cacheable(value = "productCache")
@Override
public List<ProductDTO> findAllByCategory(Category category) {
    
    // code omitted 

    return productDTOList;
}
```

Could you please clarify me about the following caching scenarios by assuming retrieving products by category (category1, category2, category3...):

**1.** Suppose that I first retrieve category1 from database and then if the same category is requested in expiration period, this result will be returned from cache, not from database.

If another type e.g. category2 is retrieved, then the result will be retrieved from database as it is not in cache.

Then if category1 type is retrieved again in expiration period, this will be returned from cache as it had already been cached. Is this scenarios all true?

**2.** As far as I see, caching works by resultset. When retrieving 3 product categories one by one, it caches each category separately, (not all of them in a cache) is that true?

**3.** Assume that I retrieve category1 and then retrieve category2. Then there is an update that affects category1 results. In this case I think I should clear cache related to this resultset after each CREATE or UPDATE. So, can I delete only the first resultset? Because I use cache name as "productCache" that is used for service method.

Comment: Caching works based on the key (by default the method arguments) and it will cache the result of the method call. It doesn't do anything related to result sets or whatever mechanism you use to retrieve objects. Also if this is a cache for JPA based entities I would strongly suggest to not use `@Cacheable` but use the 2nd level caching of your JPA provider, for proper integration (which takes care of updates/deletes etc.).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you mean *"productCache"* by method arguments in my example? On the other hand, if it caches the result of the method call, how it detects a new result is cached before (for example retrieving Category1 for 2nd time)?

Comment: Please also read this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial it will clarify a lot

Comment: could you also clarify about using the 2nd level caching of my JPA provider? I am new and have really no idea about caching and the approaches you suggested.

Comment: I already read that documentation before switching to Redis for caching. So, how can I delete caching only for the result of category2 for example? Is it possible and how?

Comment: To remove it depends on your method signature. But as stated if this is for JPA I would strongly suggest reading up on your provider (probable Hibernate) and how to enable and integrate 2nd level caching instead of using this.

Comment: But I already integrated Redis and use it for caching without any problem. I think I just need to use `cacheManager.getCache("productCache").clear();` in related CREATE and UPDATE methods. Am I wrong?

Comment: @M.Deinum Any reply please?

Comment: Any modification needs to clear the cache, and inevitably you will forget it somewhere with all consequences. As stated it is better to integrate this with your JPA provider as it takes care of that (and more) out-of-the-box.

Comment: How can I get the cached values? And should I use key in `@Cacheable` annotation in order to differentiate the cache.